# How to force object always look on our view point?

Tags: rendering, constraints

I need the objects to always face the view, view of viewport, not camera view. I mean view in general meaning.

Comment: What do you mean? One way is to parent the object to the camera if you want to see the same face all the time.

Comment: Hello, in practice, your *title* should introduce users to your question. The *body* of your post should include your question and what you have tried and what has not worked.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth I Add more details in body of my post, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Damped Track object constraint from the object constraints tab. Depending on what you want, you may have to rotate the object to make it the correct orientation  (it's 'facing the right way' for what you want)

Choose the camera as the target if you want it to always face the camera (the viewer)

And make view locked on Camera view.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I need object to face view of viewport, not a view of camera.

Comment: @WhiteRaven You can potentially just have a camera locked and aligned to your view, so that it follows you, and then your object will face you constantly. You can't have an object perpetually face towards the current given viewport angle afaik

Comment: Now I understand, thanks.